# Проблемы с MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archlinux

У меня Arch Linux, поэтому у меня нету MySQL Server, и мне пришлось выкручиваться установкой обычного MySQL, но когда я пытаюсь зайти, то мне выдаёт ошибку:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

А когда я пытаюсь удалить MySQL командой `pacman -R mariadb` - выдаёт ошибку:

> error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
>   :: galera: removing mariadb breaks dependency 'mariadb'

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "обычный MySQL"?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL server в Arch Linux заменен на MariaDB. Это форк MySQL server.

Удалить MySQL и MariaDB мешают зависимости.

Вероятнее всего вы забыли инициировать базу:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
mysql_secure_installation
```

И запустить демон:

```
systemctl enable mysqld
systemctl start mysqld
```

Можно прочитать подробнее в [документации](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MySQL_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).